# Can objects with private copy constructors be thrown?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, private, copy-constructor

I've come across some exceptions issue that is unclear to me. In C++, when an object is thrown it is first copied to a temporary object, and the temporary object is then passed to the catching code. The copy involves the use of the object's class copy constructor. AFAIK, this means that if a class has a private copy constructor, it can't be used as an exception. However, in VS2010, the following code compiles and runs:

```
class Except
{
    Except(const Except& other) { i = 2; }
public:
    int i;
    Except() : i(1) {}
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Except ex1;
        throw ex1;          // private copy constructor is invoked
    }
    catch (Except& ex2)
    {
        assert(ex2.i == 2); // assert doesn't yell - ex2.i is indeed 2
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this legal?

Comment: Try adding prints or debugging and see the order of calls, maybe things don't execute exactly as you think they do.

Comment: I get same behaviour with VS2010 but it fails [here](http://ideone.com/RlOjl) with gcc v4.3.4.

Comment: Could be that the temporary object is what is constructed, and the copy is optimized away. Similar to return value optimization.

Comment: No Visual Studio 10 gives an error for your code.

Comment: @DumbCoder, it compiled and executed for me with VS2010.

Comment: @hmjd It compiles fine surprisingly, but when you write it shows an error saying the copy constructor is inaccessible. I am using the Express edition.

Comment: Try to remove & in expression Except& ex2

Comment: @BoPersson: copy elision still requires an accessible copy constructor.

Comment: @zabulus: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Checking that the copy construction error would trigger there ?

Comment: @selalerer - debugging shows the private copy c'tor is indeed entered, at the expected time. @zabulus - it doesn't compile, as one would expect, but the error is at the `catch` line. My problem is with the `throw`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not legal. Standard 15.1/5

> If the use of the temporary object can be eliminated without changing
>   the meaning of the program except for the execution of constructors
>   and destructors associated with the use of the temporary object
>   (12.2), then the exception in the handler can be initialized directly
>   with the argument of the throw expression. **When the thrown object is a
>   class object, and the copy constructor used to initialize the
>   temporary copy is not accessible, the program is ill-formed** (even when
>   the temporary object could otherwise be eliminated). Similarly, if the
>   destructor for that object is not accessible, the program is
>   ill-formed (even when the temporary object could otherwise be
>   eliminated).

Comment: Wow that's amazing, never would have guessed it could happen. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.

> 15.1.5 When the thrown object is a class object, the copy/move constructor and the destructor shall be accessible,
>   even if the copy/move operation is elided